# Collect user input data - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to collect input data from the user and record it in a certain page. You will see what my program does (full code down below). But the code below, is having two problems.

**first problem:** The Data in the HistoryPage class is not getting stored correctly. For example when I press A then type 50, The HistoryPage will store it as 'Subtracted 50 on A (and the date)'. But when I enter a second input, such as 30 on B, the Page will show 'Subtracted 30 on A', 'Subtracted 30 on B'. Thus, the Value of A also changes.

**Second problem:**

```
count++;
print(count);
historyList.add(History(data: text.data, dateTime: DateTime.now()));
```

This part of the code is not working. I tried to make 'text' a global variable. But I cannot change the constructor in the class Tile with a global variable.

**full code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './globals.dart' as globals;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HistoryPage()),
            );
          },
          child: Text(value.toString()),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          child: Center(child: Text("Spent")),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Type()),
            );
          },
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
}

class Spent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              leading: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)),
            ),
            body: Center(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                  Tile(
                    text: Text(
                      "A",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tile(
                    text: Text(
                      "B",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tile(
                    text: Text(
                      "C",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]))));
  }
}

class Tile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Text text;
  Tile({this.text});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Type()),
        );
      },
      child: text,
    );
  }
}

class Type extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TypeState createState() => TypeState();
}

class TypeState extends State<Type> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
        TextFormField(
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            controller: _controller,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number),
        FlatButton(
          child: Text("Subract"),
          onPressed: () {
            if (int.tryParse(_controller.text) == null) return;
            globals.enteredValue = int.parse(_controller.text);
            setState(() {
              value -= globals.enteredValue;
            });
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()),
            );
            count++;
            print(count);
            historyList.add(History(data: text.data, dateTime: DateTime.now()));
          },
        ),
      ])),
    ));
  }
}

int value = 0;
int count = 0;
List<History> historyList = [];

class History {
  String data;
  DateTime dateTime;
  History({
    this.data,
    this.dateTime,
  });
}

class HistoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HistoryPageState createState() => HistoryPageState();
}

class HistoryPageState extends State<HistoryPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()),
                );
              }),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: historyList.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(
                    ' Subtracted ${globals.enteredValue} on ${historyList[index].data}   ${historyList[index].dateTime.toString()}'),
              );
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

**globals.dart**

```
library numbers.globals;

int enteredValue = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: class `History` add `enteredValue` attribute

```
class History {
```

int enteredValue;

Step 2: `historyList.add` need `enteredValue`

```
historyList.add(History(
            enteredValue: int.parse(_controller.text),
```

Step 3: class `Type` need `final Text text;`

```
class Type extends StatefulWidget {
  final Text text;
  Type({this.text});
```

Step 4:  `MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Type(text: text)),`

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './globals.dart' as globals;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HistoryPage()),
            );
          },
          child: Text(value.toString()),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          child: Center(child: Text("Spent")),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Spent()),
            );
          },
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
}

class Spent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              leading: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)),
            ),
            body: Center(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                  Tile(
                    text: Text(
                      "A",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tile(
                    text: Text(
                      "B",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tile(
                    text: Text(
                      "C",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]))));
  }
}

class Tile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Text text;
  Tile({this.text});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Type(text: text)),
        );
      },
      child: text,
    );
  }
}

class Type extends StatefulWidget {
  final Text text;
  Type({this.text});

  @override
  TypeState createState() => TypeState();
}

class TypeState extends State<Type> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
        TextFormField(
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            controller: _controller,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number),
        FlatButton(
          child: Text("Subract"),
          onPressed: () {
            if (int.tryParse(_controller.text) == null) return;
            globals.enteredValue = int.parse(_controller.text);
            setState(() {
              value -= globals.enteredValue;
            });
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()),
            );
            count++;
            print(count);
            historyList.add(History(
                enteredValue: int.parse(_controller.text),
                data: widget.text.data,
                dateTime: DateTime.now()));
          },
        ),
      ])),
    ));
  }
}

int value = 0;
int count = 0;
List<History> historyList = [];

class History {
  int enteredValue;
  String data;
  DateTime dateTime;
  History({
    this.enteredValue,
    this.data,
    this.dateTime,
  });
}

class HistoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HistoryPageState createState() => HistoryPageState();
}

class HistoryPageState extends State<HistoryPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()),
                );
              }),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: historyList.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(
                    ' Subtracted ${historyList[index].enteredValue} on ${historyList[index].data}   ${historyList[index].dateTime.toString()}'),
              );
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```